Adding horizontal line within \left\{ and \begin{aligned} \end{aligned} environment
I have the following code:
\begin{align}
p \sim \frac{\pi^2}{90} \nu T^4, \,\,\,\nu = 
    \left\{
    \begin {aligned}
         & \,\,+3, & (\mathrm{Pions:}\,\, \pi^0, \pi^+, \pi^+)  \\
         & +16,  &\,\,( \mathrm{Gluons:}\,\,(N_c^2-1) \cdot 2 )  \\
         & +21\sim 31.5, &\,\,(\, \mathrm{Quarks:}\,\, N_c \times N_f \times 2\times2\times\frac{7}{8})                    
    \end{aligned}
\right .
\end{align}

How do I change this code so that I can draw the horizontal line, and also show the last line, which is just a sum of the first three lines, just like the image (made in Powerpoint and IguanaTex) that I've posted down below? 

You can use booktabs and its \midrule command.
The input can also be simplified.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
p \sim \frac{\pi^2}{90} \nu T^4,
\quad
\nu =
\begin{cases*}
+3,           & Pions:  $\pi^0$, $\pi^+$, $\pi^+$  \\
+16,          & Gluons: $(N_c^2-1) \cdot 2$ \\
\midrule
+21\sim 31.5, & Quarks: $N_c \times N_f \times 2\times2\times\frac{7}{8}$
\end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}

With cases* the second column starts out in text mode.
I'd not use parentheses around the items in the second column, but you're free to add them. I'm a bit perplexed about the inconsistency in the multiplication symbol, which is \cdot in the second line and \times in the final one.
Avoid align for a single equation.


Thanks! This is (almost) what I was looking for!

@ArkanineOkhotsk What's the “almost” about?

Well, if you take a look at the picture I've posted, yours is slightly different because mine has another line, making it a total of 4 lines while yours has 3 lines in total. But I got the gist of what you were saying, so the problem's essentially solved. Thank you for your help!
